# multiple io errors when trying to up services with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

## Intro

I'm running `docker-compose up` on a set of services on a `docker-compose.yaml` file and getting multiple IO errors. The services are unable to run.

I use Windows 11 22H2 with wsl2 and Docker Desktop v4.27.1 (136059). The machine is a Dell G15 i7 with 16GB RAM.

## Compose

Here is the `docker-compose.yaml` that is not working:

```yaml
version: "3"
volumes:
  data:
    name: data

services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts-db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

  autenticador-api:
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    build:
      context: ./autenticador-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./autenticador-api:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9231:9231
    environment:
      - DB_DIALECT=postgres
      - DB_HOST=postgresdb
      - DB_LOGGING=${DB_LOGGING}
      - DB_NAME=neosigner
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_SCHEMA_AUTENTICADOR=autenticador
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - NODE_ENV=loc
      - NODE_PORT=3000
      - POOL_ACQUIRE=${POOL_ACQUIRE}
      - POOL_EVICT=${POOL_EVICT}
      - POOL_IDLE=${POOL_IDLE}
      - POOL_MAX=${POOL_MAX}
      - POOL_MIN=${POOL_MIN}

  web-app:
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
      - autenticador-api
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./web:/app
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

## Autenticador

The `autenticador-api` service is a typical typescript nodejs backend.

[image]

Here it's Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm i -g npm@9.6.7
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

RUN chown -R 528635140:528600513 "/root/.npm"
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

## Web

The `web-app` service is a Vue 2 single-page-application

[image]

The Dockerfile of the web app is:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

## Errors

When I run `docker-compose up`, docker downloads the images and ignites the containers. When the CMD is fired, I get multiple IO errors in the command line. Below are some error from those two services, but there are many more from other services. They all have this IO mark.

Here the IO error for the node backend

[image]

And here multiple IO errors from the web app

[image]

## It seems to be a Windows setup problem

I already formatted the machine and tried again, but the errors remain.

It just works if I get the same repo and run `docker-compose up` in a Ubuntu machine.

I thank any help you could give me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the code that generates the error, and any supporting files. There's nothing in the question describing where you believe the files are coming from and should be available in the container. It's also not clear which of the services is generating the error.

Comment: @BMitch, I edited the question to include more details. I hope I can be more precise this time. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the error messages in plain text?  One thing I see here is that you're overwriting all of both images' contents with mounts of various sorts.  If you delete the `volumes:` blocks in the two application containers, does it work better?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. Thanks for the feedback. Are you talking about the services section? The docker composition is used for active development in the local machine. The services form an integrated system where the dev updates code continuously, every update is reflected in the docker service, and then the dev interacts with the actual system running. Sure, it is ignorance on my part, but I can't see a way to activate that model without volumes like "- ./web:/app".